# Get the list of buckets from MinIO with PL/SQL SDK Dbms_cloud

Tags: oracle, plsql, minio

Hello I've been struggling to find the correct URI format to communicate with MinIO server running in a container
I'm just looking for the correct format of URI because i get

> ORA-20006: Unsupported object store URI - https://play.min.io:9000 ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 1278 ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 5316 ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.AWS_LIST_BUCKETS", line 8

NB : im using  https://play.min.io:9000 to test

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aws_list_buckets( 
credential_name IN VARCHAR2,
region IN CLOB
) RETURN CLOB 
AS 
resp dbms_cloud_types.RESP;
BEGIN
resp := dbms_cloud.send_request(
    credential_name,
    uri => 'https://play.min.io:9000',
    method => dbms_cloud.METHOD_GET
);
RETURN dbms_cloud.get_response_text(resp);
```

END aws_list_buckets;

Comment: ORA-20006 (anything in the 20000 range) is a custom application error code, not an Oracle-generated one. You'll have read your application code to determine what it is expecting.

Comment: i think the format of URI is not supported because when i looked in documentation i couldn't find something related to MInIO, if you can explain to me how to get my buckets from MinIO server with this dbms_cloud package i'll be gratefull

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. This is not an issue with the URI format, this is an issue with AUTHORIZED cloud provider.

Please issue the following command onto the CDB as SYS :

`insert into C##CLOUD$SERVICE.dbms_cloud_store values ('AMAZON_S3','%play.min.io',null,1); commit ;`

ALSO please note that you MAY BE required to use 443 port (not in your sample code but for list_objects method of dbms_cloud, it seems to be hardcoded).

regards,

Virgile-Maximilien CREVON